# Reconciling two versions of Taylor's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, manifolds

> **Lemma $1.4$** (Taylor's theorem with remainder). Let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ star-shaped with respect to a point $p=\left(p^{1}, \ldots, p^{n}\right)$ in $U$. Then there are functions $g_{1}(x), \ldots, g_{n}(x) \in C^{\infty}(U)$ such that
> $$
> f(x)=f(p)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x^{i}-p^{i}\right) g_{i}(x), \quad g_{i}(p)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}(p) .
> $$

I am not used to this form of Taylor's theorem. Previously, I have seen in the single variable case that there exists a point between the approximation and the point we know for which is equal to the difference between the Taylor polynomial and the function.

> **5.15 Theorem** Suppose $f$ is a real function on $[a, b], n$ is a positive integer, $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on $[a, b], f^{(n)}(t)$ exists for every $t \in(a, b)$. Let $\alpha, \beta$ be distinct points of $[a, b]$, and define
> $$
> P(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(\alpha)}{k !}(t-\alpha)^{k} .
> $$
> Then there exists a point $x$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
> $$
> f(\beta)=P(\beta)+\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n !}(\beta-\alpha)^{n} .
> $$

How can I reconcile these two viewpoints? is the $\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}$ what we take to be our $g$ in the single variable case? In the second, I haven't thoguht to view the remainder as a smooth function I've taken for granted that there is some constant which gives you equality. Is there something about the remainder in the second theorem which is $C^\infty$?

Comment: For the first theorem, you write $f(x)-f(p)=\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}f(p+t(x-p))\,dt$ and use the chain rule. I've written a more detailed explanation before, but can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @peek-a-boo My question is more how can I see that these two forms are essentially doing the same thing?

Comment: THe significance of $g_i$ being $C^{\infty}$ is that in particular you can write it as $g_i(x)=g_i(p)+ O(\|x-p\|)$, so that gives you a second-order bound on the 'remainder'. Note that in Taylor's theorem, usually we don't care about having an 'exact formula', rather we care about bounds on the error. Now, since you tagged manifolds in particular, this way of writing $f$ is useful for when you want to consider derivations on a smooth manifold.

Comment: @peek-a-boo What if the function is not $C^\infty$ but rather is $C^n$? Does the same theorem hold but the remainder would be $C^n$ as well?

Comment: If $f$ is $C^{k}$ with $k\geq 1$, then the $g_i$ are $C^{k-1}$. This 'loss' of differentiability is one of the reasons why working with $C^{\infty}$ is convenient.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Are the two theorems equivalent in some sense? How do I know some $g_i$ exists in the context of the second theorem?

Comment: going from the second to the first seems a little awkward because the dependence of $x$ on $\beta$ is unnatural. That $x$ is obtained by an application of the mean-value theorem in some sense, which is generally a pure existence theorem. The first lemma is proved by the FTC as I mentioned in the first post, and from that proof, the degree of smoothness is easily deduced.

Comment: The first statement is the first order version of what is known as the integral form of the remainder. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder. It is better than the second statement, because it gives an explicit formula for the remainder. Offhand, I do not know how to prove the first statement from the second. I believe that the first implies the second by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: With both forms, it is clear that the $k$-th order remainder formula holds if $f$ is $C^k$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo You say the second is a pure existance theorem. With the second theorem, is this saying that the magnitude of the $(n)$ th derivative between the two points bounds how large the error can be? And the existance is just to show that there is some point which makes this true? So even when we don't know which point this is, we know the magnitude can be no more than the $(n)$ th derivative magnitude?

Comment: Perhaps there's some confusion here? The first statement is about a function of $n$ variables and gives an explicit formula for the $0$-th order Taylor exxpansion with remainder. The second statement is about a function of $1$ variable and gives a formula for the $(n-1)$-th order Taylor expansion with remainder.

Comment: @SamKirkiles, yes. You can estimate the error using the second statement. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder

Comment: @peek-a-boo You say "The significance of $g_{i}$ being $C^{\infty}$ is that in particular you can write it as $g_{i}(x)=g_{i}(p)+O(\|x-p\|)$". Wouldn't this only hold if you have aboslute continuity? How do we know the error is on the order of $\|x-p\|$ I thought we just have there exists some delta for which this holds. Does this mean we apply Taylor's theorem again?

Comment: yes, the basic Taylor's theorem again.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I get it now thank you!